# Putty+PKI+Pageant not working on vSphere not working

Tags: vmware, putty

I am trying to use PKI to connect to multiple **VMWare vSphere** guest OS, which have installed **OpenSSH** 5.6 over SSH2, using **PuTTY** and **Pageant**.
I've created the keys and and configured Putty but somehow no key exchange is happening (that I can see) when I try to connect to them. However, when I used the exact same process on a physical Xenial server, it worked flawlessly. I can log-in correctly using Passwords-based authentication, but not thru PKI.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?
Kind regards!

Comment: Not enough detail here to determine what the problem could be, and it looks to be a networking or configuration error, rather than an information security issue. For example, can you ping the virtual machines from the client you're running Putty on? Can you log in with a password? If you scan the machines, can you see port 22 listening?

Comment: Ok,thanks. I will edit my question's details. Yes I can ping, and yes I can log on with password authentication. The only problem is using Private-Public keys. OpenSSH config looks ok and putty certainly does work on other non-vSphere Hosts.

Comment: (1) check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or other location if nonstandard config) on the 'bad' server exists, both dir and file owned by you and readable by 'user' (dir 5xx or 7xx, file usually 4xx or 6xx) and not writable by 'group' or 'other', and contains a line whose first two fields (or first two after options) match _exactly_ the values displayed by puttygen (or the values in the good server's file) (2) look at server log at the time of a failed attempt (3) turn on PuTTY logging for 'SSH packets' before a connection attempt and look at that file, and if still unclear add it to your Q.

Comment: PS: SSH public keys use Public Key Cryptography (PKC) but not Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) -- except kinda sorta OpenSSH's rarely used and very idiosyncratic certs, and those aren't supported by PuTTY at all.

Comment: It seems that on the virtual host, **sshd_config** had _RSAAuthentication_ set to _NO_, and the _AuthorizedKeysFile_ was set to `/etc/ssh/keys-%u/authorized_keys` instead of the default `%h/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Who knows why. I'll adapt to that. Thanks for your input and insight @dave_thompson_085!

Comment: Finding authorizedkeys is what mattered. `RSAAuthentication` is only for SSH **version 1** which is long broken and should not be used and normally is not by Putty. `PubkeyAuthentication` is the setting that matters for v2, and in OpenSSH 6.8 up (thus not your case) also `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`.

Comment: Exactly @dave_thompson_085, thanks for your input and follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## - Why the problem:

OpenSSH Server builtin on **ESXi**, which is disabled by default, has a different configuration (*/etc/ssh/sshd_config*) than typical Linux/Ubuntu based OpenSSH. The major difference lies in the path of the accepted authorized keys:

## - The configuration:

Typical Ubuntu (Xenial) OpenSSH config file:

```
#Authentication:
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

ESXi vSphere host OpenSSH config file:

```
# Authentication:
PermitRootLogin yes
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc
PasswordAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/keys-%u/authorized_keys
```

## - The solution:

- Move the *authorized_keys* file to /etc/ssh/keys-(user)/authorized_keys.

  ## OR:
- Change the line in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* which has *AuthorizedKeysFile* to point to the location of your authorized_keys file.